# Dividing higher-order algebraic expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

I've been self-studying from Stroud & Booth's amazing "Engineering Mathematics", and am currently on the "Algebra" section.

I've been working with division of algebraic expressions, and the book explains how to solve the simpler ones, such as:

$$(2{y}^2 - y - 10) \div (y + 2)$$

But, for the practice exercises, I have one that I absolutely have no clue where to start, and none of the examples or problem sets so far in the book come even close to it:

$$\frac{2r^3 + 5r^2 - 4r^3 + 3}{r^2 + 2r - 3}$$

Can anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rl}
    2r + 1 \\[-3pt]
   r^2+2r-3 \enclose{longdiv}{2r^3+5r^2-4r+3}\kern-.2ex \\[-3pt]
      \underline{2r^3+4r^2-6r\quad\:\:} \\[-3pt]
      r^2+2r+3\, \\[-3pt]
      \underline{\: r^2+2r+3} \\[-3pt]
      \:6\,
  \end{array} \\[5pt]\begin{aligned} &\therefore 2r^3+5r^2-4r+3 \\ &= (2r+1)(r^2+2r-3) + 6 \\ &= (2r+1)(r-1)(r+3) + 6\end{aligned}
$$

or,

$$
\frac{2r^3+5r^2-4r+3}{r^2+2r-3} = \underset{\text{quotient}}{\underbrace{2r+1}} + \overset{\text{remainder}}{\overbrace{\frac{6}{r^2+2r-3}}}
$$

Comment: I really like your solution, but unfortunately, I missed a power in the numerator when posing the question - it's not $4r$ it's $4r^3$.

Comment: @neuron Are you sure? Since now you have two terms of $\color{red}{r^3}$ which you can easily simplify: $\color{red}{2r^3} + 5r^2 \color{red}{- 4r^3} + 3$. Additionally, it gives a not-as-nice-looking of an answer.

Comment: My bad, it just $-4r$. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the equation $$2y^2-2y-10=0$$ we get
$$y^2-\frac{1}{2}y-5=0$$ so $$y_{1,2}=\frac{1}{4}\pm\sqrt{\frac{81}{4}}$$ so we get $$y_1=\frac{5}{2}$$ or $$y=-2$$ so you can write
$$\frac{(y+2)(y-\frac{5}{2})}{y+2}$$
Your second quotient can be written as
$$\frac{2r^3+5r^2-4r+3}{r^2+2r-3}=2\,r+1-3/2\, \left( r+3 \right) ^{-1}+3/2\, \left( r-1 \right) ^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed solution, but unfortunately, I missed a power in the numerator when posing the question - it's not $4r$ it's $4r^3$.

Comment: So it is $$\frac{-2r^3+5r^2+3}{r^2+2r-3}$$?

Comment: No, sorry, the original that you answered is correct: $$\frac{2r^3+5r^2-4r+3}{r^2+2r-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$2r^3+5r^2-4r+3=2r\left(r^2+2r-3\right)+\left(r^2+2r-3\right)+6=(2r+1)(r^2+2r-3)+6$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{2r^3+5r^2-4r+3}{r^2+2r-3}=\frac{(2r+1)(r^2+2r-3)+6}{r^2+2r-3}=2r+1+\frac{6}{r^2+2r-3}$$